# angular ui grid column dropdown filter blank option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

While using angular ui grid we are using selectOptions to populate dropdown options as column filter. Something similar to the following code:

```
   angular.module('exampleApp', ['ui.grid'])
   .controller('exampleCtrl', ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants', function($scope, uiGridConstants) {
var animals = [
  { id: 1, type: 'Mammal', name: 'Elephant' },
  { id: 2, type: 'Reptile', name: 'Turtle' },
  { id: 3, type: 'Mammal', name: 'Human' }
];

var animalTypes = [
  { value: 'Mammal', label: 'Mammal' },
  { value: 'Reptile', label: 'Reptile'}
];

$scope.animalGrid = {
  enableFiltering: true,
  columnDefs: [
    {
      name: 'type', 
      field: 'type', 
      filter: { selectOptions: animalTypes, type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT }
    },
    { name: 'name', name: 'name'}
  ],
  data: animals
};
}]);

    <link href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="exampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
    <h1>UI Grid Dropdown Filter Example</h1>
    <div ui-grid="animalGrid" class="grid"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This shows dropdown filter options for each column but with an extra empty option. How do I remove the empty/blank option or replace the empty/blank option with a 'All' text?

Comment: Great, just a small thing: there is not even a single line of code in your question, how you expect anyone to help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a [custom filter](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/306_custom_filters).

For your code snippet you would need to change the `label` property in `animalTypes` to `id`, and also add an option of 'All':

```
var animalTypes = [
  { value: 'All', id: '' },
  { value: 'Mammal', id: 'Mammal' },
  { value: 'Reptile', id: 'Reptile'}
];
```

Then modify the `columnDef` for the `type` column as follows:

```
columnDefs: [
  {
    name: 'type', 
    field: 'type',
    // template for rendering a custom dropdown box
    filterHeaderTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-filter-container" ng-repeat="colFilter in col.filters"><div my-custom-dropdown></div></div>', 
    filter: { 
      // initialize the filter to 'All'
      term: '',
      // the dropdown options (used in the custom directive)
      options: animalTypes
    }
  },
  ...
],
```

Please note that you will need to use the `filter.term` property to initialize the filter to 'All'. If you don't you will find that a blank option is inserted at the top of the dropdown box when the grid loads. Initializing the drop down prevents this from happening.

You can then define a custom drop down directive to render a select box containing the `animalTypes` options:

```
app.directive('myCustomDropdown', function() {
  return {
    template: '<select class="form-control" ng-model="colFilter.term" ng-options="option.id as option.value for option in colFilter.options"></select>'
  };
});
```

Please see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLabrew9/3/) for a working example

Comment: How to get the 'All' field when you are filling the animalTypes values and labels dynamically ?

Comment: Do you have any code you could share to show how you are filling the animalTypes?